# javascript script.src attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes

I want to use `"function duckie() { console.log('quack'); }"` and not a url to some javascript source file for script.src's value. Is there a way to do it?

```
function addScript() { 
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src="function duckie() { console.log('quack'); }";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?
The answer below by xdazz seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: tell your motive of doing that. Bcoz if you want to load this function   on document load, there are anonymous way of doing that

Comment: Why's the point point of this

Comment: I want to do this in android java: 
`webview.loadUrl("javascript: (function() { var script=document.createElement('script'); script.type='text/javascript'; script.src='<path to local android file>'; document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script); })()");` 
But my version of android does not allow local file access

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change src to text to add the function on calling `addScript`

```
function addScript() { 
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.text="function duckie() { console.log('quack'); }";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: yes this is also one posibility. If my answer not help then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way..

```
function addScript( src ) {
  var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
  s.setAttribute( 'src', "function duckie() { console.log('quack'); }" );
  document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback guys. I tried most of the suggestions and here's how I got to inject a .js file  for every webpage webkit loads.

1. Read a local js file to a string.
2. Append that string to `script.text` after creating a document element with type `text/javascript`
3. Call `javascript: (function() { <programmatically formatted string dynamically creating webpage script element >})()"` inside an overridden webview `onPageFinished`.

Verified working on Android 4.0.3–4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 15)